# An expression is recognized as a function

Tags: function, expression, ocaml, currying

I am trying to implement some graph algorithms with the OCaml language.
I've made a graph type with a two dimension array which refer to the graph I want to use

And here is my function to get the list of all the point linked to a v point :

```
let voisins graphe v =
  let rec voisinsAux tableau i res =
    if i = Array.length tableau then
      res
    else if v != i then
      voisinsAux tableau (i + 1) (ajouter res (Array.get tableau i))
    else
      voisinsAux tableau (i + 1) res
  in voisinsAux (Array.get graphe.matrice v) 0
;;
```

I guess it's not clean but I think it's OK.
The problem is when I test it, I'm getting this:

```
let listeVoisins = voisins g 3;;
val listeVoisins : int list -> int list = <fun>
```

How can I get a fun type since `voisins g 3` should be an `int list` type expression?
Why my `listeVoisins` is not executed as an expression?

Comment: `voisinsAux` takes three arguments, but you're only giving it two.

Comment: The slightly longer explanation is that functions in OCaml are curried, so leaving off an argument will have it return a partially applied function.

Answer (score 4):

Functions in OCaml are curried. We have syntax that lets us work with the concept more conveniently, but a function takes a single value and returns a single value.

Of course, *functions are values*, so a function can return another function which in turn takes an argument and returns something. The function it can return has access to every value that was in scope when it was created. Research "closures."

Consider your code, with the inner function rewritten to reflect this:

```
let voisins graphe v =
  let rec voisinsAux =
    fun tableau ->
      fun i ->
        fun res ->
          if i = Array.length tableau then
            res
          else if v != i then
            voisinsAux tableau (i + 1) (ajouter res (Array.get tableau i))
          else
            voisinsAux tableau (i + 1) res
  in voisinsAux (Array.get graphe.matrice v) 0
```

That is *not* pretty to look at, but it's functionally the same as what you wrote.

You've then only applied two arguments to `voisinsAux` which takes three. This means what you've gotten back is a function that takes one argument (`res` - apparently an `int list`) and *then* calculates the `int list` result you're looking for.